# AWS CDK - Add description to key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How do I add a description to a key pair using Amazon AWS CDK? There doesn't seem to be a description property and the key is created with an empty description for the associated entry in the parameter store on the AWS console.

Comment: There seems to be no description field when you create a key pair in the console. You can use tags in the console and CDK.

Comment: @Sri, that's correct. However, when you use the CDK, it creates an associated key in the parameter store. I was referring to the description for the associated key. Thanks for the tags suggestion.

Comment: @Sri, could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no description field when you create a key pair in the console. You can use tags in the console and CDK.